# Passing variables extracted from array to the url when register globals is ON

Tags: php, arrays, url, parameters, extract

I have a function which takes a parameter such as shown below:

```
functionname("$var",array('x'=>value1,'y'=>value2));
```

I want to extract an array by using `extract();` and pass it to the URL as a parameter so I can enter it in the address bar like so:

```
http://localhost/folder/file.php?var=value1&x=value2&y=value3
```

Comment: So you want http://localhost/folder/file.php?var=value1&x=value2&y=value3 to create an array with those values?

Comment: or do you want to convert the array into a string formatted that way?

Comment: i am most bothered about those to array variable. I dont know how would i pass value to it from the url.previously i was directly assigning the values to the array like 'x'=>value1 and 'y'=>value2 and my function would give me the output.But now i wana pass value from the url.I dont want to recreate an array instead i want to convert into strings.

Comment: Are you looking for [http_build_query](http://cz2.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)?

Comment: I have an image resizing script .How do i pass parameterized variable to the url in function resize("$imagefile",array('w'=>300,'h'=>300)); i am using $imagefile to pass value from url when register globals is On. using same way i want to pass width and height like 
http://localhost/folder/example.php?imagefile=dog.jpg&w=300&h=500.